# NaNs in statsmodels output of Multinomial Logistic Regression

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I am running a multinomial logistic regression following [Multinomial Logistic Regression](https://www.datasklr.com/logistic-regression/multinomial-logistic-regression). Many `coef` of the statsmodels output have nan `std err`, `z`, `P>|z|` and `CI`. Why? Since I am neither a statistics nor a Python guru, I appreciate any help!

This is my code:

```
X = trials[['lookRight_fract', 'lookLeft_fract', 'lookUp_fract', 'lookDown_fract']]
y = trials['decision_resp']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 5)
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(y_test.shape)

model1 = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, multi_class='multinomial', penalty='none', solver='newton-cg').fit(X_train, y_train)
preds = model1.predict(X_test)

#print the tunable parameters (They were not tuned in this example, everything kept as default)
params = model1.get_params()
print(params)

#Print model parameters
print('Intercept: \n', model1.intercept_)
print('Coefficients: \n', model1.coef_)

#Calculate odds ratio estimates
np.exp(model1.coef_)

#Use statsmodels to assess variables
logit_model=sm.MNLogit(y_train,sm.add_constant(X_train))
logit_model
result=logit_model.fit()
stats1=result.summary()
stats2=result.summary2()
print(stats1)
print(stats2)
```

And output:

```
(48, 4)
(12, 4)
(48,)
(12,)
{'C': 1.0, 'class_weight': None, 'dual': False, 'fit_intercept': True, 'intercept_scaling': 1, 'l1_ratio': None, 'max_iter': 100, 'multi_class': 'multinomial', 'n_jobs': None, 'penalty': 'none', 'random_state': 0, 'solver': 'newton-cg', 'tol': 0.0001, 'verbose': 0, 'warm_start': False}
Intercept: 
 [ 0.19649031 -0.17631272 -0.00349682 -0.01668077]
Coefficients: 
 [[-3.99096383  0.45505743 -1.3728297   5.10522641]
 [ 1.62594837  6.02251539 -7.22514652 -0.59962996]
 [ 5.83854865  0.45699354 -4.514776   -1.78426301]
 [-3.47353318 -6.93456636 13.11275222 -2.72133345]]
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.621395
         Iterations 9
                          MNLogit Regression Results                          
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:          decision_resp   No. Observations:                   48
Model:                        MNLogit   Df Residuals:                       36
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                            9
Date:                Sat, 30 Apr 2022   Pseudo R-squ.:                  0.5452
Time:                        19:40:44   Log-Likelihood:                -29.827
converged:                       True   LL-Null:                       -65.586
Covariance Type:            nonrobust   LLR p-value:                 7.669e-12
====================================================================================
 decision_resp=left       coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const                  -0.3728        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
lookRight_fract         5.6169        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
lookLeft_fract          5.5674        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
lookUp_fract           -5.8522        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
lookDown_fract         -5.7049        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
decision_resp=right       coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const                  -0.2000   3.06e+07  -6.54e-09      1.000   -5.99e+07    5.99e+07
lookRight_fract         9.8295   3.02e+07   3.25e-07      1.000   -5.92e+07    5.92e+07
lookLeft_fract          0.0019   2.98e+07   6.31e-11      1.000   -5.85e+07    5.85e+07
lookUp_fract           -3.1419   3.03e+07  -1.04e-07      1.000   -5.94e+07    5.94e+07
lookDown_fract         -6.8895   3.02e+07  -2.28e-07      1.000   -5.91e+07    5.91e+07
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
decision_resp=up       coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const               -0.2132        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
lookRight_fract      0.5174        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
lookLeft_fract      -7.3897        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
lookUp_fract        14.4857        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
lookDown_fract      -7.8266        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
====================================================================================
                                 Results: MNLogit
===================================================================================
Model:                    MNLogit                Pseudo R-squared:       0.545     
Dependent Variable:       decision_resp          AIC:                    83.6539   
Date:                     2022-04-30 19:40       BIC:                    106.1084  
No. Observations:         48                     Log-Likelihood:         -29.827   
Df Model:                 9                      LL-Null:                -65.586   
Df Residuals:             36                     LLR p-value:            7.6694e-12
Converged:                1.0000                 Scale:                  1.0000    
No. Iterations:           9.0000                                                   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
decision_resp = 0      Coef.      Std.Err.      t      P>|t|     [0.025     0.975]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           const      -0.3728          nan     nan       nan        nan        nan
 lookRight_fract       5.6169          nan     nan       nan        nan        nan
  lookLeft_fract       5.5674          nan     nan       nan        nan        nan
    lookUp_fract      -5.8522          nan     nan       nan        nan        nan
  lookDown_fract      -5.7049          nan     nan       nan        nan        nan
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
decision_resp = 1  Coef.     Std.Err.      t    P>|t|      [0.025         0.975]   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            const -0.2000 30559987.2179 -0.0000 1.0000 -59896474.5150 59896474.1151
  lookRight_fract  9.8295 30210940.9011  0.0000 1.0000 -59212346.2757 59212365.9347
   lookLeft_fract  0.0019 29826907.6174  0.0000 1.0000 -58459664.6983 58459664.7021
     lookUp_fract -3.1419 30314951.7578 -0.0000 1.0000 -59416216.7802 59416210.4965
   lookDown_fract -6.8895 30160460.8454 -0.0000 1.0000 -59113423.9037 59113410.1247
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
decision_resp = 2      Coef.      Std.Err.      t      P>|t|     [0.025     0.975]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           const      -0.2132          nan     nan       nan        nan        nan
 lookRight_fract       0.5174          nan     nan       nan        nan        nan
  lookLeft_fract      -7.3897          nan     nan       nan        nan        nan
    lookUp_fract      14.4857          nan     nan       nan        nan        nan
  lookDown_fract      -7.8266          nan     nan       nan        nan        nan
===================================================================================
```

Comment: most likely (almost) perfect collinearity, Do the left and right fractions add to 1? Did you get a Hessian inversion warning when calling `fit()`.

Comment: @Josef: Yes, you are right. All fractions of looking time add to 1. When I run the regression with looking time in seconds, the output is correct. I would prefer to run it with the fractions instead of time in seconds. Is there something I can do to run it with the fractions? I do not get a Hessian inversion warning.

Comment: you need to drop one of the fractions for each category. As in the "dummy variable trap" we need to drop one of the columns that makes it equal to the constant.