# statsmodel multinomial logistic regression outputs all nan values

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I'm trying to fit a multinomial logreg with statsmodel.

```
X = sm.add_constant(df)
logreg_model = sm.MNLogit(y[:n], X).fit()
```

Where df is a one row dataframe (just because I'm trying each variable isolately to find out which of them is causing the problem) with the following values:

```
        debt
0       0.00
1       0.00
2       0.00
3       0.00
4       0.00
5       0.00
6       0.00
7    4474.35
8       0.00
9       0.00
10      0.00
11      0.00
12      0.00
13      0.00
14      0.00
15      0.00
16   1587.51
17      0.00
18      0.00
19      0.00
20      0.00
21      0.00
22      0.00
23      0.00
24      0.00
25      0.00
26      0.00
27      0.00
28      0.00
29      0.00
30      0.00
31      0.00
32      0.00
33      0.00
34      0.00
35      0.00
36      0.00
37      0.00
38      0.00
39      0.00
40      0.00
41      0.00
42      0.00
43      0.00
44      0.00
45      0.00
46      0.00
47      0.00
48      0.00
49      0.00
```

The problem is that when I run that code, I get two warnings:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  eXB = np.column_stack((np.ones(len(X)), np.exp(X)))
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  return eXB/eXB.sum(1)[:,None]
```

But I should be able to ignore the first one [according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726490/overflow-error-in-pythons-numpy-exp-function), whereas the second usually arises when I have nans in my df, which is not the case.

And the problem is that, whenever I get these warnings, MNLogit outputs this:

```
Dep. Variable:                      y   No. Observations:                   50
Model:                        MNLogit   Df Residuals:                       12
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                           19
Date:                Thu, 08 Jun 2023   Pseudo R-squ.:                     nan
Time:                        14:19:33   Log-Likelihood:                    nan
converged:                       True   LL-Null:                       -138.74
Covariance Type:            nonrobust   LLR p-value:                       nan
==============================================================================
       y=6       coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const             nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
debt              nan        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
```

I checked out [this](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72070816/nans-in-statsmodels-output-of-multinomial-logistic-regression) thread but didn't find any useful answer. I also tried normalizing the variable with sklearn's StandardScaler but didn't work either.

Comment: What you're seeing is infinity (`np.inf`) divided by infinity. Your debt column has values that are too large when used in the exponential function, e.g. `np.exp(4474.35) == np.inf`. So, `np.isnan(np.inf/np.inf) == True`.

Comment: try to rescale your explanatory variables, e.g. debt /1000, Large values of the explanatory variables cause problems in optimization if exp is used. To check this, you could divide all explanatory variable by max(exog) or max(exog) / 10. If that also does not work, then there might be a data problem, e.g. perfect separation or prediction.